# php str_replace produces strange results

Tags: str-replace

I am trying to replace some characters in a text block. All of the replacements are working except the one at the beginning of the string variable.

The text block contains:
`[FIRST_NAME] [LAST_NAME]`, This message is to inform you that...

The variables are defined as:

```
$fname = "John";
$lname = "Doe";

$messagebody = str_replace('[FIRST_NAME]',$fname,$messagebody);
$messagebody = str_replace('[LAST_NAME]',$lname,$messagebody);
```

The result I get is:
`[FIRST_NAME]` Doe, This message is to inform you that...

Regardless of which tag I put first or how the syntax is `{TAG} $$TAG` or `[TAG]`, the first one never gets replaced.

Can anyone tell me why and how to fix this?
Thanks

Comment: I don't see any problem with your code. I just tested. Can you paste your `$messagebody` variable? I want to see how you defined it, and what it contains.

Comment: If `$messagebody = '[FIRST_NAME] [LAST_NAME]';`, the code works for me.

Comment: $messagebody comes from an sql table with a field called message_body which is defined as a type text.

Comment: If I put something in front of the string it works. Strange. $messagebody = 'START:'.$messagebody;

Answer (score 0):

Until someone can provide me with an explanation for why this is happening, the workaround is to put a string in front and then remove it afterward:

`$messagebody = 'START:'.$messagebody;`

do what you need to do

`$messagebody = substr($messagebody,6);`

I believe it must have something to do with the fact that a string starts at position 0 and that maybe the str_replace function starts to look at position 1.